# How to sort the array by using `_key` in this code?

Tags: php

How to sort the array by using `_key` in this code?

```
Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [_key] => 50180
                [group] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [id] => 50180
                        [name] => CriticalChain
                    )

            )

        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [_key] => 2357895
                [group] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [id] => 2357895
                        [name] => Data Modeling
                    )

            )

        [2] => stdClass Object
            (
                [_key] => 1992105
                [group] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [id] => 1992105
                        [name] => SQL Server Users in Israel
                    )

            )

        [3] => stdClass Object
            (
                [_key] => 37988
                [group] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [id] => 37988
                        [name] => CDO/CIO/CTO Leadership Council
                    )

            )

        [4] => stdClass Object
            (
                [_key] => 4024801
                [group] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [id] => 4024801
                        [name] => BiT-HR, BI & IT Placement Agency
                    )

            )

        [5] => stdClass Object
            (
                [_key] => 37845
                [group] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [id] => 37845
                        [name] => Israel Technology Group
                    )

            )

        [6] => stdClass Object
            (
                [_key] => 51464
                [group] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [id] => 51464
                        [name] => Israel DBAs
                    )

            )

        [7] => stdClass Object
            (
                [_key] => 66097
                [group] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [id] => 66097
                        [name] => SQLDBA
                    )

            )

        [8] => stdClass Object
            (
                [_key] => 4462353
                [group] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [id] => 4462353
                        [name] => Israel High-Tech Group
                    )

            )

        [9] => stdClass Object
            (
                [_key] => 4203807
                [group] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [id] => 4203807
                        [name] => Microsoft Team Foundation Server
                    )

            )

    )
```

Comment: use [ksort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [usort](http://php.net/usort) or loop through it use _key as your array's keys and sort the array by key :

```
$newArray = array();
foreach($arr as $item){
    $newArray[$item->key] = $item;
}
ksort($newArray);
```